# A quantitative version of Pełczyński's property ($V^{*}$)

Tags: banach-spaces

Let me first fix some notations. Let $A$ be a bounded subset of a Banach space $X$. Set $$wk_{X}(A)=\widehat{d}(\overline{A}^{w^{*}},X)=\sup\{d(x^{**},X):x^{**}\in \overline{A}^{w^{*}}\},$$ where $\overline{A}^{w^{*}}$ denotes the $weak^{*}$ closure of $A$ in $X^{**}$. Let $T\in \mathcal{L}(X,Y)$. We set 
$$uc(T)=\sup\{\limsup_{n}\|Tx_{n}\|: (x_{n})_{n}\in l^{w}_{1}(X), (x_{n})_{n}\subset B_{X}\},$$ where $l^{w}_{1}(X)$ denotes the space of all weakly unconditionally Cauchy series in $X$. We say that a Banach space $X$ has a quantitative version of Pełczyński's property ($V^{*}$) if there is a constant $C>0$ such that for every space $Y$ and every operator $T: Y\rightarrow X$, one has $$wk_{X}(T)\leq C\cdot uc(T^{*}).$$ Clearly, if a space $X$ has a quantitative version of Pełczyński's property ($V^{*}$), then $X$ has the original Pełczyński's property ($V^{*}$). A natural question arises:

Question 1: Is there a space $X$ which has the original Pełczyński's property ($V^{*}$) but fails the quantitative version of Pełczyński's property ($V^{*}$)?

We say that a space $X$ is $C$-weakly sequentially complete if for every bounded sequence $(x_{n})_{n}$ in $X$, one has $$ca((x_{n})_{n})\leq C\cdot \delta((x_{n})_{n}),$$ where $ca((x_{n})_{n})=\inf_{n}\sup\{\|x_{k}-x_{l}\|:k,l\geq n\},$ and $\delta((x_{n})_{n})$ denotes the diameter of the set of all $weak^{*}$-cluster points of $(x_{n})_{n}$ in $X^{**}$.

Question 2: If a space $X$ has a quantitative version of Pełczyński's property ($V^{*}$), is $X$ $C$-weakly sequentially complete for some $C>0$?

This question is a quantitative version of a Pełczyński's result: If a space $X$ has the Pełczyński's property ($V^{*}$), then $X$ is weakly sequentially complete.

Comment: Aleksander Pełczyński. https://pl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aleksander_Pe%C5%82czy%C5%84ski -- it's very hard to believe that English wikipedia has no article about him. (Even the article in the Polish wikipedia is very far from complete or adequate).

Comment: @WłodzimierzHolsztyński,  Thank you for your suggestion. I have made some corrections.

Comment: Dongyang Chen, you're very kind. Until a few years ago Polish diacritics were virtually unavailable on Internet (why, even mathematic symbols were not included for a long time into the extended ascii cod and similar; instead they had a smiling face and cards *color* symbols like hearts, spades, ...). We still have a long way to go to cover languages which are farther removed from the 26 character Latin (English :-)) alphabet a-z. --- I wish I could say something about your ***Question*** but to me it's too advanced, even too technical (my fault).